# How to get all questions marked duplicate of a certain question through SEDE?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, data-explorer

Is there a way to find out all the questions that have been marked duplicate of a specific question, given its ID via SEDE? I know there's a Linked section to every question that links to duplicates and other linked items for each question, but I wanted to know if it's possible to find the number of duplicates based on the target ID.

Comment: Typing "duplicate" in the search box ought to help.  [This one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/434740/find-posts-with-over-x-duplicate-targets-linking-back) should be a decent one to work from, just edit it to make it select the specific RelatedPostId.

Comment: @HansPassant Forgive me, but I'm not much of a SQL person. How would I select RelatedPostId instead of getting the number of dupes from many questions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This should do it for you](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/874017/1080467/get-questions-closed-as-dup-of-particular-question).  Just input the ID of the question you want to search and run the query.  Thanks @HansPassant for pointing to a good starting point (and @jon.doe12231 for making such initial query).

Code if curious:

```
select distinct *
from (
  select PostId as [Post Link]
   
  from PostLinks
   join Posts q on q.Id=RelatedPostId

  where LinkTypeId=3
  and RelatedPostId = ##relatedpostid##

) d
```

Comment: @pnuts - why not? Quite straight forward.http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/874210/dupes-recursive?relatedpostid=451415

Comment: that is the purpose of `Path NOT LIKE CONCAT('/', pl.PostId, '/'))` in the query. though I just noticed that I omitted the % characters so this wont currently work as desired. Fixed version http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/874219/dupes-recursive?relatedpostid=451415

Comment: @pnuts 284 when deleted posts are included

Comment: This SEDE query is so awesome I've added it to the "**[Advanced Search Helper, Saved Search (Bookmarks), and Navigation Improvements](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011)**" userscript with additional modifications. Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmMKW.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/aywJH.png

Answer (score 9):

An extension of the query in the other answer (to include dupes of dupes and deleted posts) is in the query titled [Dupes Recursive](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/874400/dupes-recursive)

```
DECLARE @QuestionId          INT = ##QuestionId:int?451415##,
        @IncludeDeletedPosts BIT = ##IncludeDeletedPosts:string?true##;

/*To act as temporary index as base table doesn't have useful one*/
CREATE TABLE #PostLinks(
   RelatedPostId INT,
   PostId        INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (RelatedPostId, PostId));

INSERT INTO #PostLinks
SELECT RelatedPostId,
       PostId
FROM   PostLinks
WHERE  LinkTypeId = 3;

WITH R
     AS (SELECT @QuestionId                                          AS PostId,
                0                                                    AS Level,
                CAST(CONCAT('/', @QuestionId, '/') AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS Path
         UNION ALL
         SELECT pl.PostId,
                Level + 1,
                CONCAT(Path, pl.PostId, '/')
         FROM   #PostLinks pl
                JOIN R
                  ON R.PostId = pl.RelatedPostId
         WHERE  Path NOT LIKE CONCAT('%/', pl.PostId, '/%'))
SELECT PostId AS [Post Link],
       Level,
       Path
FROM   R
WHERE  Level > 0
       AND ( @IncludeDeletedPosts = 1
              OR PostId IN (SELECT Id FROM Posts) )
ORDER  BY Path
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: Why are you adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`?

Comment: So it can generate a plan optimal for the value of the bit variable. No need to access Posts if this is true.

Comment: Looks quite similar to my [DupeTree](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/793984/dupetree-find-all-duplicates-of-a-question?PostId=451415) query, although mine doesn't (yet) have the option to find deleted duplicates. On the other hand, mine does have more output columns, and it only shows the shortest path from each duplicate to the target (which I consider a feature, although I suppose some might disagree).

Comment: Please make `IncludeDeletedPosts` default value to `false`, as we shouldn't encourage to browse through deleted content.

Comment: @Cœur it doesnt encourage browsing through deleted content. Deleted items are returned as a bare QuestionId that isnt even hyperlinked. Also if someone earns the privilege to view deleted posts it is up to them how they use it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Good idea, it hadn't occurred to me that a question could have multiple duplicate paths to the same ancestor.