# Most frequent questions for a tag combination

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, filtering, frequent

Tags have the Frequent tab/filter, but, AFAIK, the search result page doesn't have a Frequent tab. I'm wondering if there is a way to find an automatically created "FAQ" for searches of two or more tags (combo-tags),

Let’s say that I want to build make a proposal for of a list of Frequent / Interesting question to be included in the [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) wiki or another more suitable place organized by "combo-tags" like the following:

- [[google-apps-script][google-sheets]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D&searchOn=3) 49,627 results
- [[google-apps-script][triggers]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Btriggers%5D&searchOn=3) 2,410 results
- [[google-apps-script][web-application]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Bweb-applications%5D&searchOn=3) 1,928 results
- [[google-apps-script][custom-function]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Bcustom-function%5D&searchOn=3) 787 results
- [[google-apps-script][add-on]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%5Badd-on%5D&searchOn=3) 341 results

There is a question about using SEDE to find all the questions marked as duplicate of one question, but I think that what I need is a query to find the top questions having two or more tags by number of linked questions.

Is this the best way to find the top more referenced questions for any search of two or more tags?

Related

- [What does the Frequent tab mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344306/1595451)
- [How to get all questions marked duplicate of a certain question through SEDE?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371024/1595451)

---

I found a couple of SEDE queries ([Most frequent duplicate targets](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1630878/most-frequent-duplicate-targets) and [Deleted questions having the given two tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1098355/deleted-questions-having-the-given-two-tags), forked the first one -> [Most frequent duplicate targets having two tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1651511/2011541/most-frequent-duplicate-targets-having-two-tags)... I will review this tomorrow

```
WITH Duplicates AS (
SELECT RelatedPostId, COUNT(*) AS times_used_as_dupe_target
  FROM PostLinks
  WHERE LinkTypeId = 3 -- duplicates
  GROUP BY RelatedPostId
)
SELECT TOP 100 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY times_used_as_dupe_target DESC) AS Rank,
  Id AS [Post Link], times_used_as_dupe_target
  FROM Posts
  INNER JOIN Duplicates
    ON Id = RelatedPostId
  WHERE (Tags LIKE '%<##Tag1?google-apps-script##>%') AND (Tags LIKE '%<##Tag2?google-sheets##>%')
  ORDER BY times_used_as_dupe_target DESC
```

Comment: Something to explore [Generating h-index rankings with SEDE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369548/1595451) (this is about ranking users, not questions, and the tag versions are for a single tag, but might give an starting point)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [filter to show questions with multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script%2bgoogle-sheets?tab=Frequent), which has several views, including "frequent".

[image: filter: tagged with the following tags (with two in the box), sorted by frequent]

I think you could even have a filter that combines all five of your bullets. (Use the "or" keyword.)

Comment: Looks like this is available through the "more" tab on the search page (above the "Score" sort): https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFYuw.png

Comment: @zcoop98 That's a tag page, not a search. If you put both tags in the search bar it will not take you to that page.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if I access combination of two tags [using tagged/google-apps-script+google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+google-sheets), then the [frequent tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script%2bgoogle-sheets?tab=Frequent) is available.

But still, looking at SEDE might be useful - since similar solution can be used for some other searches (which do not have the frequent tab).

Moreover, the results from SEDE can be easily downloaded if you want modify them further in some way.

---

This isn't really that different from the query you posted - some things I've added are:

- Using the PostTags table to search for tags.
- The parameter linktypes to choose which types of links you want.

I.e., you can use [linktypes=1,3](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1651719/most-frequently-linked-questions?linktypes=1,3) to count all linked questions. Or you can restrict it to counting only one LinkTypeId. Since you're asking about duplicates, I will post the queries below with `linktypes=3`.

- [Looking among all questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1651719/most-frequently-linked-questions?linktypes=3)
- [Only the questions with the given tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1651720/most-frequently-linked-questions-in-the-given-tag?linktypes=3&tagname=google-apps-script)
- The questions [having tag1 and tag2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1651724/most-frequently-linked-questions-with-tag1-and-tag2?linktypes=3&tagname1=google-apps-script&tagname2=google-sheets)

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. They look that will help me to find candidates to add to the FAQ list in the [tag:google-apps-script] wiki (and possible others).